# python: split() efficiency vs character crawling method

Tags: python, string, performance, file, split

I have a very large text file to parse for some information. Each line I do checks for certain keywords (I call them "flags"). Once I find the "flag", I then call the below method and gather the data that comes right after the flag (usually just a name or number) to find the information after the flag I used the below method(which works):

```
def findValue(string, flag):
    string = string.strip()
    startIndex = string.find(flag) + len(flag)
    index = startIndex
    char = string[index:index+1]
    while char != " " and index < len(string):
        index += 1
        char = string[index:index+1]
    endIndex = index
    return string[startIndex:endIndex]
```

However, it is much easier if I just use the split() with white spaces as separators and then take the next item in the list rather than "crawling" the characters.

The log files I am parsing are really large (around 1.5 million or more lines), so I would like to know if and how much it would hurt my efficient to use split() on lines compared to my current method.

Comment: `char = string[index:index+1]` creates a new string at each loop, very unefficient. `split (string[startIndex:])` would be much faster than your current method.

Comment: Does `string` contain the entire contents of the file, or just a single line?

Comment: "string" is just a single line

Comment: Also, and correct me if I'm wrong, isn't `string[i]` equivalent to `string[i:i+1]`? And _maybe_ a bit more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some timing tests using string `'oabsecaosbeoiabsoeib;asdnvzldkxbcoszievbzldkvn.zlisebv;iszdb;vibzdlkv8niandsailbsdlivbslidznclkxvnlidbvlzidbvlzidbvlkxnv'`, searching for `'8'`, each 100000 times:

**Your Method**: 2.156 seconds

**`str.split`**: 0.151 seconds

Another test, that is somewhat more realistic: `'hello this is for stack overflow and i absolutely hate typing unecessary characters'`

**Your Method**: 0.317 seconds

**`str.split`**: 0.267 seconds

A final test, with the above string multiplied 100 times:

**Your Method**: 0.325 seconds

**`str.split`**: 7.376 seconds

Whatever this says.

In your case, with super large strings, I would definitely use your function!

Comment: The last difference is probably due to the fact that his function only looks for the *first* occurrence of `' '`, whereas `split` would look for all the occurrences of `' '`.

Comment: Thank you for that data, the lines are in face very long. You just saved me from a lot of work changing my findVaule implementaion

Answer (score 1):

Python's `split()` function is almost certainly written in C, which means it will be faster than the equivalent code if you wrote it in Python.  However, if you are just calling `split()` on a single line (not all 1.5 million of them), the difference won't be huge.

However, why bother even using `split()` when you just need the next item in the list?  This may be the most efficient of any approach:

```
def findValue(string, flag):
    startIndex = string.find(flag) + len(flag)
    endIndex = string.find(' ', startIndex)
    if endIndex == -1:
        return string[startIndex:]
    else:
        return string[startIndex:endIndex]
```

Comment: You might want to include the case where the end index extends to the end of the line (no space in the string). In that case just make endIndex = len(string) + 1. In your implementation, it's -1 if no space char is found, , which truncates the last character (second slicing parameter is exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a file object pointing to the file:

```
current_item = ""
char = file.read(1) 
while char:
  if char != " ":
     current_item += char
  else:
     do_something_about_the_item(current_item)
     current_item = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try python's regular expression tool, the `re` module, which particularly suited for parsing text files.
Some examples:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/07/python-regex-examples/